# Check if two arrays are equal or not

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, equality, unordered-map

I am trying to know if the two given arrays are equal or not, irrespective of permutation of elements but contains the same elements and frequency of all the elements must be same.

```
    int SameArray(int arr1[], int arr2[], int N, int M)
    {
        unordered_map<int, int> ump;
        if(N == M)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                ump[arr1[i]]++;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i< M; i++)
            {
                if(ump.find(arr2[i]) != ump.end())
                    ump[arr2[i]]--;
            }
            if(ump.empty())
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

it's not showing any errors but output is always 0.

Comment: You don't want the resulting map to be empty; you want to check that it only contains 0s. And bear in mind what happens if there is a value in the second array that isn't in the first at all.

Comment: Simply use [`std::is_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation)

Comment: @BoBTFish You're correct, but technically that's not going to lead to problems because the sum of all map entries must be zero (if `M==N`). Thus if there would be a negative entry missing due to this bug, there must be a positive entry somewhere, leading to the overall correct result.

Comment: Sort both and then check that they're equal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [`std::is_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation):

```cpp
bool SameArray(const std::vector<int>& arr1, const std::vector<int>& arr2) {
    return std::is_permutation(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), arr2.begin(), arr2.end());
}
```

I took the liberty of changing your function return to `bool` and taking [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)s as function parameters since this is C++ and not C.

If you're curious about how `std::permutation`'s comparasion works, look at its [example implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_permutation#Complexity).

Comment: You need to check if the sizes are equal before calling `std::is_permutation` in order to avoid undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Fareanor Actually I think they don't have to be equal, just `arr1.size() <= arr2.size()`

Comment: @nada Yes but you need to ensure it. And since the function is supposed to verify equality, checking if the sizes are equal before calling `std::is_permutation` makes sense (to avoid to call the function when not needed --> save time).

Comment: @HeetMehta if this answer solves your problem, consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: The "same size" check is trivially achieved by passing `arr2.end()` too. See the linked documentation. This solution remains a one-liner with that.

Comment: However, it must be noted that this approach is worst-case `O(N²)`, whereas the unordered map approach in the OP is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 4):

The condition in the if statement

```
if(ump.empty())
```

is not correct. The map can not be empty provided that the passed arrays do not have zero sizes.

Instead of the condition you could use the standard algorithm `std::all_of`. Also there is no sense to pass the two sizes of the arrays because if they are not equal to each other then it is evident that the arrays are not equal each other.

Also the array parameters shall be specified with the qualifier const because they are not changed in the function.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the function can be defined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

bool SameArray( const int a1[], const int a2[], size_t n )
{
    sstd::unordered_map<int, int> m;

    for ( const int *p = a1; p != a1 + n; ++p ) ++m[*p];
    for ( const int *p = a2; p != a2 + n; ++p ) --m[*p];


    return std::all_of( std::begin( m ), std::end( m ), 
                        []( const auto &p) { return p.second == 0; } );
}

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 20;

    int a1[N] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
    int a2[N] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << SameArray( a1, a2, N ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if every key in the map has a value of zero. Instead of `ump.empty()` you can do the below code.

```
for (auto& it: ump) {
    if(it.second != 0) {
        return 0;
} 
return 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

`ump[arr2[i]]--;` is not going to delete the key. You have to check whether the value of each entry is zero or not. I have added below statement before `return 1` -

`for (auto it = ump.begin(); it != ump.end(); ++it ) if(it->second != 0) return 0;`

```
int SameArray(int arr1[], int arr2[], int N, int M)
{
    unordered_map<int, int> ump;
    if(N == M)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            ump[arr1[i]]++;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< M; i++)
        {
            if(ump.find(arr2[i]) != ump.end())
                ump[arr2[i]]--;
        }
        for (auto it = ump.begin(); it != ump.end(); ++it ) if(it->second != 0) return 0; 
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```